# Showing certain links based on permissions in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

The problem seems rather simple... I'm sure thousands of people have already figured this out, so maybe I'm overthinking it. How can I hide or show a link in my navigation bar based on the user's permission level? I am using custom roles (not MVCs) and storing that information in a database. The effect I want is pretty simple

**_Layout.cshtml**

```
...

@if(user.IsAdmin)
    show link
...
```

There are several solutions to this I've found on the web and here on SO, but most seem to violate the MVC constructs.

Most of the solutions I found involved probing for data from within the view, which I'm pretty sure is bad practice. Other solutions involve utilizing the session variables from within the view to decide what is shown and what isn't. Isn't this also against best practices as views should not be able to decide on content?

The only "pure MVC" way I can think of doing this is to incorporate the value of `IsAdmin` into each of my view models, which seems like more hassle than it's worth. I suppose it's also possible to create a javacript solution where I use AJAX to figure out the admin status, then have it inject an html element into my navigation bar.

What is the proper way to handle this? Am I simply misunderstanding the best practices?

Comment: have you consider using the mvcsitemap provider?

Comment: I am unaware of such a service. Will read into it..

Comment: Why not `@if (User.IsInRole("Admin")) ...`? That seems to be the standard way of doing this, even if it's not the most "*pure*".

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use a partial view within the layout?  Something like this:

```
@Html.Partial(actionName: "NavigationLinks", controllerName: "Navigation")
```

That way, you can preserve the MVC conventions: the view can be stand-alone, and the navigation controller injects the model (whether from session data, or wherever).